# Can Terraform -destroy ignore the current terraform code

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to force terraform -destroy to ignore the current terraform code and use remote state to determine what needs to be removed?

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour of `destroy` anyway?

Comment: I wanted to be sure so I added some typos in the code and the -destroy pipeline exited with syntax error (could be just compiling the code). I have renamed many resources and just want to be certain that destroy does not use any elements defined in the current terraform code files. The documentation here is somewhat confusing as I am newish to terrform. https://developer.harness.io/docs/first-gen/continuous-delivery/terraform-category/terraform-destroy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When planning in the "destroy" [planning mode](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#planning-modes) and then applying such a plan, Terraform still needs to evaluate some parts of the configuration, including (but not limited to):

- `provider` blocks that describe how to configure the providers, since those will need to handle the API calls required during planning and destroying.
- `provisioner` blocks which have `when = destroy` to indicate they should run during the destroy phase.

Because these destroy-time configuration elements can also refer to other objects in the configuration, Terraform must therefore still evaluate most of the configuration to ensure that all of the necessary data is available.

However, in particular Terraform will rely on the content in the state rather than in the configuration when destroying a resource instance, so Terraform will still destroy any objects that are tracked in the most recent state snapshot but are not currently described in the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I think I ran into some validation against changes in new code.

Comment: This may be outside of the scope of this question, but would you think it would be doable to create a scaled down project that includes only the two parts you mentioned above, targeting the state of the larger project. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's hard to remove `resource` blocks without removing their `provisioner` blocks because they are nested inside, but _in principle_ it can be possible to delete everything except the `provider` blocks, as long as all of those blocks are in the root module as recommended in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Terraform destroy deletes all resources (not data) in the current state file, even if the configuration files have changed while an apply has not been done.

Comment: Thanks for the verification. I guess the compilation of the current config files is just part of a step in destroy.

Comment: Well it is doing something with the current config. We changed our kms keys around and have a condition based on count    = (var.kms_key_id == ""...  and it is failing because it can't determine the count. Is it best practice to revert code to the state during the last successful apply? I was trying to avoid this.